# Authenticate with client certificate without CORS

Tags: windows, angular, authentication, cors, ssl-certificate

I want to be able to request a distant API with my Angular 5 app.

The API server is asking a SSL-certificate in order to authenticate the client.

This certificate is distributed - by the company that provide the API - to a limited number of users, by handing them directly an USB key that contains the certificate (which is delivered by a trusted CA).

That means that I don't have access to a .pem or .crt file. Instead, the certificate is locally stored in the Windows AD (or local store) and I can't export the private key (for obvious security reason).

But the CA is also providing drivers that allow to register a certificate (if your USB key is plugged) to your favorite browser.

So I tried with the following test project:

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit}                       from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClient}                              from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title    = 'TEST API';
    url      = 'https://myAPIurl/lgcMessagerieInbox';       
    result   = '';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    testAPIcall(): void {
        this.http.get(this.url)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>
        {{ title }}
    </h1>

     <button class="btnStandard" type="button"  (click)="testAPIcall()" >TEST</button>

    <div *ngIf="result">
        {{ result }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The first good news was that the browser automatically detected the fact that the API was asking a certificate and opened a windows so I could select a certificate, enter my pin code and send the http request.

But it failed because the server doesn't accept CORS requests ( https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ ).

So I though of using the local proxy provided by Angular in order to redirect the request so the browser doesn't block it because of different domain name. But then I wasn't able to pass the certificate through the proxy.

My questions are :

- Is there a way to read the certificate directly on the windows local
  store from my Angular app? *I'm almost certain there is not if I
  trust what I've been searching on internet over the past 3 days.*
- How can I pass a certificate through a proxy (Angular or anything else)?
- If the two options above are not available, do you know a way to access the API knowing the constraints (using an other techno but it must be
  cross-platform)?

Comment: Did you get it to work? Or did you find a workaround?

Comment: For the moment I try to make a dotnet core application to directly access the certificate but I don't managed to make it work on osx / unix systems.